# _dbs.couch keeps dropped db information

Tags: couchdb, fauxton

I recently wondered why my `/var/lib/couchdb/_dbs.couch` files kept its filesize when I dropped an entire database. It seems like, anytime I create a (test) db it gets written and stored there, but it never gets entirely removed when I delete the database again (Fauxton 2.1.1).
I can even see/search for the database names within that file.

Any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: This behaviour is happening even with db compaction process enabled?

Comment: `compactions` is set to `_default` value `[{db_fragmentation, "70%"}, {view_fragmentation, "60%"}]`.
But what has that to do with anything? Is the behaviour normal or is there any way to clean the _dbs.couch?

Answer (score 1):

I point you to an answer to a similar question:
[why does CouchDBs _dbs.couch keep growing when purging/compacting DBs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826795/why-does-couchdbs-dbs-couch-keep-growing-when-purging-compacting-dbs)

The answer comes from a CouchDB contributor